Using Block Coordinate Descent for Convex Optimization with Quadratic Constraints
In solving the optimization problem $$min _{X, Y} f(X, Y) $$ $$\text { s.t. } \operatorname{tr}\left(X X^T\right)+\operatorname{tr}\left(Y Y^T\right) \leq P$$
, where both $f_X​(Y)$
and $f_Y​(X)$
are convex, can I use the block coordinate descent method to solve this problem and ensure the convergence of the solution process due to the presence of the quadratic constraint? How should I handle this quadratic constraint?

Convergence to stationary point? It’s better to explicitly show the objective function
